# Как понять куда нажала мышь?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Как осуществить проверку места нажатия мыши: если нажатие было на UI панели, то НЕ выполнять условие(Ниже в коде) и так же обратно? Unity

Код нажатия и выполнения условий

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if ()
            {
                Debug.Log("1");
            }
            else if ()
            {
                Debug.Log("2");
            }
            else if ()
            {
                Debug.Log("3");
            }                
        }
```

Comment: Это можно реализовать через невидимые кнопки

Answer (score 0):

Input.MousePosition для того, чтобы узнать вектор-положение относительно экрана